# Want to add "..." to my gingerbread app title bar so user can get at settings

Tags: android, settings, backwards-compatibility

My app supports android phones back to gingerbread (2.3). It is written to that spec
and it uses the system supplied settings button. Some users are getting confused about how
to make the settings on certain new phones such as S5. I would like to place a settings
command right on the top line of the app as is common nowadays. But I don't want it to break
the app on older phones. Is there a way to do this and still be back compatible to 2.3.
thanks

Comment: Use sherlock library or appcompact library for action bar support, so that you can have settings on the top line of the app

Comment: Thanks. Want the library with minimal extra functions, would this be "v7 appcompat library"??

Comment: better to go with v7 appcompat library which is provided by android and sherlocklibrary updation are also got stopped .

Comment: OK I tried and tried to use the appcompat library. One problem after another, so I regrouped and read up in the developers blog. Then, I simply added "android:targetSdkVersion="14"" to my uses-sdk statement in the manifest. Now the ... is there on current devices like I wanted, but the old way still works on gingerbread level devices. Much better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I tried and tried to use the appcompat library. One problem after another, so I regrouped and read up in the developers blog. Then, I simply added "android:targetSdkVersion="14"" to my uses-sdk statement in the manifest. Now the ... is there on current devices like I wanted, but the old way still works on gingerbread level devices. Much better... –  user1644002 3 mins ago    edit